# not found: type SimplexSolver while using org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear

Tags: scala, linear-programming

I am working with scala and want to use SimplexSolver (https://opensource.googleblog.com/2009/06/introducing-apache-commons-math.html). I am using sbt, hence downloaded the .jar file for commons-math-2.2 and imported it in the code. Then I tried to use it, but it showed not found: type SimplexSolver. Following is the code snippet.

```
import org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear
class MySimplexSolver{
 val solver = new SimplexSolver()
}
```

I have a lib folder where all the .jar files are kept. Any help regarding this is appreciated. :)

Comment: have you imported `SimplexSolver`?

Comment: Oh I imported org.apache.commons.math.optimization.linear but not SimplexSolver. I did that, now it worked for SimplexSolver. Thank you.